# "'constexpr' is not valid here" error in VisualStudio 2017 but not VisualStudio 2019

Tags: c++, constexpr

I am getting the error

```
"'constexpr' is not valid here
```

and

```
E1449   explicit specialization of variable "tao::pegtl::internal::enable_control [with Rule=tao::pegtl::internal::bol]" must precede its first use ()  Pegtl \include\tao\pegtl\internal\bol.hpp   27
```

on the following line of code:

```
template<>
inline constexpr bool enable_control< bol > = false;
```

(on line 27 https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL/blob/master/include/tao/pegtl/internal/bol.hpp)

the code compiles fine under VisualStudio 2019.

What difference between VisualStudio 2017 and 2019 could account for this error? and how can I get it compiling in VisualStudio 2017?

Comment: Is that maybe a C++17 feature? Make sure your "C/C++ Language" settings (properties) are the same in the VS2017 and VS2019 projects.

Comment: @AdrianMole yes, Both are set to std:c++17, I don't know what else to check.

Comment: there is no difference in the vs 2017 and 2019 compiling process as they both use MSVC for compiling and intellisense  your problem can only be related to your c++ standard

Comment: VS2017 doesn't support C++14 fully (details depend on the version) and surely doesn't support C++17 if you use it.

Comment: @ALX23z that could explain it. Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: @pingu you could try following the error instruction. It wants the specialisation to be defined prior to usage. Can you ensure that this is the case? Generally if compiler complains for some random error that shouldn't be I try to find a workable workaround.